# How does a Hall effect ion thruster have a sea-level Isp of 800? Operates at 1 atmosphere?

Tags: propulsion, engines, communication-satellite, ion-thruster

Astronatix's [SPT-100](http://www.astronautix.com/s/spt-100.html) lists the following:

> Stechkin electric rocket engine. Used on Meteor and Gals satellites.
>
> - In Production. 1.35 kW Hall thruster.
> - Thrust variable 2 to 20 kgf.
> - Marketed in USA by Space Systems/Loral and Fakel.
> - Status: In Production. Date: -1984.
> - Thrust: 196 N (44 lbf).
> - **Specific impulse: 2,500 s. Specific impulse sea level: 800 s.**
> - Electrical Input Power: 1.35 kW.

**Question:** How does a conventional (looking) [Hall effect ion thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall-effect_thruster) have a sea-level Isp of 800? *Can it really operate at atmospheric pressure?*

**Also:** Isn't 196 *Newtons* about 1000x larger than what you might expect?

---

[image: Stechkin 1.35 kW Hall thruster]

Comment: companion question: [How does a “hybrid orbital raising system” based on R-4D (N2O4/MMH) + SPT-100 (Hall effect) work exactly? (Intelsat 38 & 39)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38000/12102)

Comment: Astronautix.... If I ever reference that site it's because I can't find the information *anywhere* else, and I always add a caveat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SPT-100 thruster is described along with several others in the paper: [Electric Propulsion Activity in Russia; IEPC-01-05](http://erps.spacegrant.org/uploads/images/images/iepc_articledownload_1988-2007/2001index/2002iepc/papers/t01/5_2.pdf), Presented as Paper IEPC-01-(05) at the 27th International Electric Propulsion Conference, Pasadena, CA, 15-19 October, 2001.

Table 2 lists its specifications:

> Nominal operation mode power, kW: 1.35
>
> Nominal thrust, mN: 80
>
> Specific impulse, s: 1600

It seems plausible that the Russian paper (and NASA) are more correct that the Astronatix site.

---

[image]

Comment: I meant more-correct than the Astronatix site; I've made an edit.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for tracking this source down.I think it's pretty obvious now that the Astronautix article is simply wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Can't speak to the sea level Isp (other than agreeing with your intuition that it's bogus), but the thrust is clearly in error.

NASA testing of the engine in 1993 showed < 100 mN thrust in vacuum, with associated Isp's between 1000 and 2000.

[source](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19940019157.pdf)

Comment: I wonder if this entry started as a copy/paste from another engine and someone simply forgot to edit the text?

Comment: The power use and vacuum Isp seem roughly consistent with what's in the NASA paper, so no idea.